# How to deploy azure bot using bot frame work composer?

Tags: azure, azure-billing

I have created an azure bot using Bot framework composer. When I tried to deploy the bot in azure I ran Into an issue `{"name":"CREATE_LUIS_AUTHORING_RESOURCE_ERROR","message":"Error - The subscription is not registered to use namespace 'Microsoft.CognitiveServices'. See https://aka.ms/rps-not-found for how to register subscriptions.","stack":"Error\n at new CustomizeError (/Applications/Bot Framework Composer.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar.unpacked/extensions/azurePublish/dist/extension.js:269072:25)\n at createCustomizeError (/Applications/Bot Framework Composer.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar.unpacked/extensions/azurePublish/dist/extension.js:269077:10)\n at AzureResourceMananger.deployLuisAuthoringResource (/Applications/Bot Framework Composer.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar.unpacked/extensions/azurePublish/dist/extension.js:269865:13)"}. See provision.Azure Bot.log in your bot folder`
What should I do to deploy this bot in azure?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To overcome this issue we need to select an S1 subscription while creating an azure bot from pricing section. [image]